# Laravel forms: Route not defined error

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have defined a resourceful route like this:

```
Route::resource('user/info/experience', 'ExperienceController');
```

And the following is what i have used in my form:

```
{!! Form::open([
                 'route'=>'user.info.experience.store',
                 'method' => 'post',               
                ]
) !!}
```

Now it's giving me the

> Route [user.info.experience] not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try clearing routes `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the route definition or in from. The problem was that there was another call to `user.info.experience` in my view which didn't exist. So I corrected that call and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Routes

```
Route::resource('user/info/experience', 'ExperienceController');
```

Form

```
{!! Form::open([
                 'route'=>'user/info/experience',
                 'method' => 'post',               
                ]
) !!}
```

or use alias:

Routes

```
Route::post('user/info/experience', array('as' => 'experience', 'uses' => 'ExperienceController@functionName'));
```

Form

```
{!! Form::open([
                 'route'=>'experience',
                 'method' => 'post',               
                ]
) !!}
```

Answer (score -2):

try `Route::resource('user.info.experience', 'ExperienceController');`